# How to replace the last word in a string

Tags: java, string

Does anyone knows how to replace the last word in a String.

**Currently I am doing:**

```
someStr = someStr.replace(someStr.substring(someStr.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1), "New Word");
```

The above code replaces every single occurance of the word in the string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a new string "from scratch" like this:

```
someStr = someStr.substring(0, someStr.lastIndexOf(" ")) + " New Word";
```

Another option (if you really want to use "replace" :) is to do

```
someStr = someStr.replaceAll(" \\S*$", " New Word");
```

`replaceAll` uses regular expressions and `\S*$` means a space, followed by some non-space characters, followed by end of string. (That is, replace the characters after the last space.)

Comment: `@aioobe` I have a string like "19-05-2011 00:00 - Some Text" Do you know how to replace the date value with empty string?

Comment: `yourString.substring(16)`? :-)

Comment: `@aioobe` Sorry to bother you again - but do you know how to fetch the date part?

Comment: @Bitmap, the api documentation is your friend!  you do it with `yourString.substring(0,16)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not far from the solution. Just keep the original string until the last index of `" "`, and append the new word to this substring. No need for `replace` here.

Comment: `@JB Nizet` Do you mean remove the `someStr=` assignment?

Comment: No, I mean the solution of aioobe... and Waldo

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is replacing the substring by "New word".

Instead you need to substring first, and then do a replace on that string.

Here's how I would do it

```
someStr = someStr.substring(0, someStr.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1) + "New word"
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
someStr = someStr.substring( someStr.lastIndexOf(" ") ) + " " + new_word;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this: someStr.`substring(0, someStr.lastIndexOf(" ")) + "New Word"`.

You can also use regular expression, e.g. someStr.repalaceFirst("\s+\S+$", " " + "New Word")

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `(^.+)b(.+$)`

Example (Replace the last **b** character)

```
System.out.println("1abchhhabcjjjabc".replaceFirst("(^.+)b(.+$)", "$1$2"));
```