# How can I use string.replace() to achieve the desired output?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  String test = 'SELECT * From `shop` WHERE `category` LIKE ';
  List cuisine = ['sneakers', 'boots', 'generic', 'male'];
  for (int i=0; i<cuisine.length;i++){
    test +='`category` LIKE '+'%${cuisine[i]}%'+' OR ';
    print(test);
  }
}
```

I want to be able to replace the last OR. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcJrX.png) is code on dartpad except there's the last or

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replaceAll`

test = test .replaceAll(" \S*$", "");

replaceAll uses regular expressions and \S*$ means a space, followed by some non-space characters, followed by end of string. (That is, replace the characters after the last space.) Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146293/how-to-replace-the-last-word-in-a-string)

Use it after `for` loop. Your full code will be

```
void main() {
  String test = 'SELECT * From `shop` WHERE `category` LIKE ';
  List cuisine = ['sneakers', 'boots', 'generic', 'male'];
  for (int i=0; i<cuisine.length;i++){
    test +='`category` LIKE '+'%${cuisine[i]}%'+' OR ';
    print(test);
  }
  test = test.replaceAll(" \\S*$", "");
  print(test);
}
```